# How to execute asynchronously or paralellize Azure PowerShell operations to spare time?

Tags: powershell, azure

In my script there are 10 endpoint configuring operations for 10 endpoints in a row like this: (please note: I am completely new to Azure PoweShell, started using yesterday, however I am experienced developer)

```
Get-AzureVM –ServiceName myservice –Name myvm | 
    Add-AzureEndpoint –Name SqlEndpoint –Protocol tcp –LocalPort 1433 `
    –PublicPort 1433 –ACL $acl | 
    Update-AzureVM
```

Unfortunatelly one takes 10-15 seconds to be completed, and they are executed in a serialized way: the next one only starts when the previous finished, so the 10 operation takes 2 minutes.

I would be happy if I can it speed up things in some way. I Suppose this serialized way is not coming from the deep Azure nature (architecture) as we can imagine 10 clients connecting and issuing the 10 operations in the very same time to the server. (I strongly hope Azure will not queue them internally and executes them 10x15 seconds...)

- Q: Can I just issue an operation with Azure PowerShell in async way, ( as a side effect losing the ability to check result?
- Q': If there is no such a generic async way, could I do this specific 10 endpoint configuring operation as one operation?

Comment: How about `Start-Job`?

Comment: Thanks, going to see what kind of animal is it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just call the `Add-AzureEndpoint` (or `Set-AzureEndpoint`) multiple times and invoke the `Update-AzureVM` cmdlet **only once** (at the end):

```
$vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName myservice –Name myvm  
Add-AzureEndpoint –Name SqlEndpoint –Protocol tcp –LocalPort 1433 –PublicPort 1433 –ACL $acl -vm $vm
Add-AzureEndpoint –Name Endpoint2 ...
Add-AzureEndpoint –Name Endpoint3 ...
...
$vm | Update-AzureVM
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds a correct specific and economic solution.

Comment: This gives an error message for me... see the temporarily edited question

Comment: I updated my answer, please try again (last line changed)

Comment: Cool thx. I think it will take 1-2 days while I get understand this pipee concept in this C/C# language family context. (although I've used and loved it a quater decade before in Unix). weird...